# What is the correct way to send array params in Wordpress API request?

Tags: wordpress

To send `_fields` param to a wordpress get request should I use

```
?_fields=field1,field2,field3
```

or

```
?_fields[]=field1&_fields[]=field2...
```

I've been debugging a request that is giving inconsistent responses depending on the query params, so was wondering if there is a definite approach for this that I might be missing

Answer (score 0):

this one ?_fields=field1,field2,field3

Comment: Would you edit your answer and confirm what you proposed works?